# Need to get the values from a column which is a list of values to other dataframe form it as new column

Tags: python, pandas

[image]
Product Price   Quantity    Group
Tv  20  1   1
Car 300 1   4
Bike    40  2   2
Laptop  80  1   3
PS4 90  1   2

Comment: you can make code or text. dont upload your example to image.

Comment: Yeah, I’m trying but this textbox not letting me,

Comment: It is of course possible. But if you can't, type it manually. you can make dataframe manually by using `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: Df01 has price list in with group number,  Df02 has Prices as column,  for price 20 the group no is 1 and for price 100 group no is 4, that’s how new column created in df02 as shown

Comment: you can make dataframe code manually like me. you just doesn't make it. Don't forget that if you don't make it,  answerer has to make it and answer it.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

we need minimal and reproducible example by code not image. lets make it.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, [10, 20, 30]], [2, [40, 50]]], columns=['group', 'price list'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['A', 10], ['B', 40], ['C', 20]], columns=['product', 'price'])
```

`df1`

```
    group   price list
0   1       [10, 20, 30]
1   2       [40, 50]
```

`df2`

```
    product price
0   A       10
1   B       40
2   C       20
```

---

**Code**

```
out = df2.merge(df1.rename(columns={'price list':'price'}).explode('price'), how='left')
```

`out`

```
    product price   group
0   A       10      1
1   B       40      2
2   C       20      1
```